# How to swipe between pages or layouts without using ViewPager or ViewFlipper?

Tags: android, layout

I am concern about the ViewPager or ViewFlipper. I don't want to use ViewPage. So I want to know how to swipe between Layout or activity. Can anyone suggest me with source code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand why you don't want to use ViewPager. You'll be able to swipe between everything you want(activity, layout). It's not difficult to use it and to customize it. There is a plenty of examples:
[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

[General](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using)

you can easily surf through the i-net to look for more examples